# Open XML WordprocessingDocument with MemoryStream is 0KB

Tags: c#, .net-core, ms-word, openxml, memorystream

I am trying to learn how to use with Microsoft's Open XML SDK. I followed their steps on how to create a Word document using a `FileStream` and it worked perfectly. Now I want to create a Word document but only in memory, and wait for the user to specify whether they would like to save the file or not.

[This document by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2010/ee945362(v%3Doffice.11)#creating-resizable-memory-streams-from-byte-arrays) says how to deal with in-memory documents using `MemoryStream`, however, the document is first loaded from an existing file and "dumped" into a `MemorySteam`. What I want is to create a document entirely in memory (not based on a file in a drive). What I thought would achieve that was this code:

```cs
// This is almost the same as Microsoft's code except I don't
// dump any files into the MemoryStream
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        doc.AddMainDocumentPart().Document = new Document();
        var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        var paragraph = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        var run = paragraph.AppendChild(new Run());
        run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello docx"));

        using (var file = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            mem.WriteTo(file);
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is a file that is 0KB and that can't be read by Word. At first I thought it was because of the size of the `MemoryStream` so I provided it with an initial size of 1024 but the results were the same. On the other hand if I change the `MemoryStream` for a `FileStream`it works perfectly.

My question is whether what I want to do is possible, and if so, how? I guess it must be possible, just not how I'm doing it. If it isn't possible what alternative do I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here:

First, unlike Microsoft's sample, I was nesting the `using` block code that writes the file to disk inside the block that creates and modifies the file. The `WordprocessingDocument` gets saved to the stream until it is disposed or when the `Save()` method is called. The `WordprocessingDocument` gets disposed automatically when reaching the end of it's `using` block. If I had not nested the third using statement, thus reaching the end of the second `using` statement before trying to save the file, I would have allowed the document to be written to the `MemoryStream`- instead I was writing a still empty stream to disk (hence the 0KB file).

I **suppose** calling `Save()`might have helped, but it is not supported by .Net core (which is what I'm using). You can check whether `Save()`is supported on you system by checking `CanSave`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a value indicating whether saving the package is supported by calling <see cref="Save"/>. Some platforms (such as .NET Core), have limited support for saving.
/// If <c>false</c>, in order to save, the document and/or package needs to be fully closed and disposed and then reopened.
/// </summary>
public static bool CanSave { get; }
```

So the code ended up being almost identical to Microsoft's code except I don't read any files beforehand, rather I just begin with an empty `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        doc.AddMainDocumentPart().Document = new Document();
        var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        var paragraph = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        var run = paragraph.AppendChild(new Run());
        run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello docx"));
    }

    using (var file = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        mem.WriteTo(file);
    }
}
```

Also you don't need to reopen the document before saving it, but if you do remember to use `Open()` instead of `Create()` because `Create()` will empty the `MemoryStream` and you'll also end with a 0KB file.

Comment: For me, calling Save() before reading the stream didn't work but moving the read outside of the inner 'using' block did. It seems .Save() has little or no effect until the document is Close()'d

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and thanks to Lance U. Matthews's response, I realized that I was never closing the MemoryStream, so here's my solution (I had to use aliases for my usings)

---

```
private MemoryStream GenerateWord(DataTable dt)
    {

        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        // Create Document
        OpenXMLPackaging.WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
            OpenXMLPackaging.WordprocessingDocument.Create(mStream, OpenXML.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true);
        // Add a main document part. 
        OpenXMLPackaging.MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
        mainPart.Document = new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Document();
        OpenXMLWordprocessing.Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Body());
        OpenXMLWordprocessing.Table table = new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Table();
        body.AppendChild(table);
        OpenXMLWordprocessing.TableRow tr = new OpenXMLWordprocessing.TableRow();
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            tr.Append(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.TableCell(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Paragraph(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Run(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Text(c.ColumnName.ToString())))));
        }
        table.Append(tr);

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                OpenXMLWordprocessing.TableRow dataRow = new OpenXMLWordprocessing.TableRow();
                for (int h = 0; h < dt.Columns.Count; h++)
                {
                    dataRow.Append(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.TableCell(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Paragraph(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Run(new OpenXMLWordprocessing.Text(r[h].ToString())))));
                }
                table.Append(dataRow);
            }
        }
        mainPart.Document.Save();
        wordDocument.Close();
        mStream.Position = 0;
        return mStream;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `mem` to `WordprocessingDocument.Create()`, which is creating the document from the (now-empty) `MemoryStream`, however, I don't think that is associating the `MemoryStream` as the backing store of the document.  That is, `mem` is only the *input* of the document, not the *output* as well.  Therefore, when you call `mem.WriteTo(file);`, `mem` is still empty (the debugger would confirm this).

Then again, the linked document does say "you must supply a resizable memory stream to [`Open()`]", which implies that the stream will be written to, so maybe `mem` *does* become the backing store but nothing has been written to it yet because the  [`AutoSave` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.autosave) (for which you specified `true` in `Create()`) hasn't had a chance to take effect yet (emphasis mine)...

> Gets a flag that indicates whether the parts should be saved **when disposed.**

I see that `WordprocessingDocument` has a [`SaveAs()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.saveas), and substituting that for the `FileStream` in the original code...

```cs
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
{
    doc.AddMainDocumentPart().Document = new Document();
    var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
    var paragraph = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
    var run = paragraph.AppendChild(new Run());
    run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello docx"));

    // Explicitly close the OpenXmlPackage returned by SaveAs() so destination doesn't stay locked
    doc.SaveAs(destination).Close();
}
```

...produces the expected file for me.  Interestingly, after the call to `doc.SaveAs()`, and even if I insert a call to `doc.Save()`, `mem.Length` and `mem.Position` are both still `0`, which does suggest that `mem` is only used for initialization.

One other thing I would note is that the sample code is calling [`Open()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.open), whereas you are calling [`Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.create).  The documentation is pretty sparse as far as how those two methods differ, but I would have suggested you try creating your document with `Open()` instead...

```cs
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
{
    // ...
}
```

...**however** when I do that `Open()` throws an exception, presumably because `mem` has no data.  So, it seems the names are somewhat self-explanatory in that `Create()` initializes new document data whereas `Open()` expects existing data.  I did find that if I feed `Create()` a `MemoryStream` filled with random garbage...

```cs
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Fill mem with garbage
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
    mem.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    mem.Position = 0;

    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

...it still produces the **exact same document** XML as the first code snippet above, which makes me wonder why `Create()` even needs an input `Stream` at all.

Comment: I have updated the question based on what you suggested I try. In the case of `Open()` vs `Create()` both methods have the same description ‍♂️, I guess I'll take a look at their implementations to see how they differ.

Comment: The difference between `Open()` and `Close()` was indeed the solution to the second update's problem! I'll mark your answer as accepted since it was key to finding the solution.

Comment: I tried it and found that your original code does work when writing to a file using `doc.SaveAs(destination)`.  I updated my answer with that and some other findings.  Also, I think your last two edits to the question should be combined into an answer since they describe how you arrived at a solution, which doesn't really belong on the question side of things.  See [Should I edit my question or post a new answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216719/699943)